# jQuery selector type on click speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

i thought that this

```js
$('.select-choice').on('click', window.callable);
```

type of selector is much better than this

```js
$('body').on('click', '.select-choice', window.callable);
```

because we are not monitoring whole body but only one element.

But weird as it seems to me results are quite oposite, do you have any idea why? Do i have my test wrong?

https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/8569/2/jquery-body-fit-onclick-filter-vs-direct---logged-now

Comment: What I understand is: you think the results are wrong and you want to know whether or not they are wrong, and why.

Answer (score 3):

Let's test it!

**First Piece of code**: Around `1` ms to `2` ms for me.

```js
let callable = () => console.log("called"),
    body = $("body"),
    btn = $(".btn"); // Class selector like in Question
    
console.time("test");
btn.on("click", callable);
btn.click();
console.timeEnd("test")

// Always around 1 ms to 2 ms.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn"></button>
```

**Second Piece of Code**: Around `2` ms to `4` ms for me.

```js
let callable = () => console.log("called"),
    body = $("body"),
    btn = $(".btn"); // Class selector like in Question
    
console.time("test");
body.on("click", ".btn", callable);
btn.click();
console.timeEnd("test")

// Around 2ms to 4ms for me.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn"></button>
```

**Result** (At least in my computer): The first snippet was faster, which is the direct one.

You thought right! It does take less time in direct event listener, and I think your reasoning behind it is also correct. I don't know about the link, because really, I don't understand anything it's saying, but maybe this test can help!

Comment: Huh, thanks. The first is also faster for me in this example. Could you please try to add for loop to have bigger sample?

Comment: @Aiphee  I don't quite understand. Perhaps you can give an example of a 'bigger sample' you mentioned.

Comment: I have tried it with for: https://jsfiddle.net/aiphee/1sxyg8j5/9/ as it seems, difference is neglectible.

Comment: @Aiphee  I don't even see an output, whether I click the test button or not. But, after clicking TEST, all I see is that `console.time` is not defined, which I suspect is because jsFiddle didn't add that functionality to its console.